# JBOSS EAP 7.0 with ActiveMQ RAR doesn't work?

Tags: jboss, jms, rar, jboss-eap-7

I have a war that has being working just fine under EAP 6.4.x  (x currently 8, but also under 6 and 4 and so on down to 6.4.0).

The WAR has some simple JMS client features to adding a message to a queue on a remote machine.      The target QBroker is ActiveMQ  5.8.0.

I use the 5.8.0 RAR to set up an adapter/connector to the remote broker and then just normal JMS client stuff to push a message into a q.    All is fine with this.

Beginning the "port" from 6.4.x to 7.0.1; and I am hung up on the amq 5.8.0 RAR stuff.     For starters -- not going to use any of the AMQ Artemis stuff that is part of EAP 7 (yet).   Initially I want to get my WAR working under 7.0 with as few changes as possible -- so leaving RAR in place is important.

Under 6.4.x, I use the standalone profile and just deploy the RAR via CLI kinda like this:

```
./jboss-cli.sh --connect -c "deploy --name=${AMQ_DEPLOY_NAME} --runtime-name=${AMQ_RAR_FNAME} ${_TMPDIR}/${AMQ_RAR_FNAME}"
```

I then use cli to set up resource adapter, connection def/factory and admin-object for the queue.

Following the same process with EAP 7.0.1, if I use the standalone profile I get

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/JMSException
```

issues while trying to enable the WAR that uses the RAR.    Ok so when I used standalone-full I get all sorts of variations of this sort of error:

```
2016-07-18 15:48:10,867 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "messaging-activemq"),
    ("server" => "default")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.messaging-activemq.default is missing [jboss.http-upgrade-registry.default]"],
    "WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
        "Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.messaging-activemq.default.jms.manager"],
        "Services that may be the cause:" => [
            "jboss.http-upgrade-registry.default",
            "jboss.naming.context.java.JmsXA"
        ]
    }
}
```

The above messages suggest something is wrong with the messaging-activemq stuff (or the built in artemis stuff).

In both cases, I do set my EJB default resource adapter to the RAR created above.

***So what am I missing on this set up?***

Some particulars about my Environment:

War doesn't have any jboss/wildfly specific DDs in it.

I do not have the AMQ RAR deployed as a static module (nor do I want to)  -- it is just a jar I have deployed - like other JAR (for DB drivers) or WARS, EJB jars, etc.

cat version.txt 
Red Hat JBoss Enterprise Application Platform - Version 7.0.1.GA

java -version
java version "1.8.0_92"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode)

uname -a 
Linux wellandf3 4.6.4-301.fc24.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jul 12 11:50:00 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

Is this NoClassDefFoundError caused by a ClassNotFoundException? If thats the case I would try to add javax.jms.api as global module.

Comment: The `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/JMSException` is definitely caused by the standalone.xml instead of standalone-full.xml being used as standalone doesnt include any JMS by default (I know I just ran into the issue) - though this doesnt help the OP out with the error he got after using standalone-full.xml ;-)